Having JetBrains WebStorm open regularly kills screen session in PuTTY
I have a very odd and very frustrating issue.
Summary
I have my Linux environment set up to automatically reconnect to any existing screen session on log in, which when combined with the WebStorm IDE from JetBrains, causes any existing SSH sessions (including any opened in the WebStorm terminal!) to disconnect from screen after a few seconds. This does NOT happen in Intellij Ultimate (2022.3 edition), but I want to use the lighter, more targeted (and massively cheaper) app.
I need to accomplish one of two things:

Stop WebStorm from generating sessions that are stealing my screen instance, or
Enhance my screen setup to prevent screen instance stealing in such cases, while allowing it in others (preferred)

What it looks like

~
16:36:37 eshields@GamingRig {~}$
 GamingRig   0 bash                               Thu  06/20  16:47
\[remote detached from 9875.pts-3.GamingRig\]
16:47:35 eshields@GamingRig {~}$

Setup
Linux Server: Windows 10 with WSL running Ubuntu latest
.bash_profile
# Move auth socket to known place so SSH forwarding works in screen after connection interrupt
# @author http://superuser.com/a/424588/541446
if [ -S "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ ! -h "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
    ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/agent.socket
fi
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/agent.socket
# If screen session exists and there is an interactive terminal, Run screen (first detaching if necessary - attach to first session if multiple)
if [ -z "$STY" ] && [[ -t 0 || -p /dev/stdin ]]; then screen -d -RR; fi

.screen_rc
# Enable agent forwarding on screen reconnects
#setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK $HOME/.ssh/agent.socket

WebStorm

version: 2024.1 running on Windows 10
new install so default settings

Further notes
I use this setup primarily in a work setting where my Linux server is not my work machine, so the screen session continues running when I'm not working, and, more importantly, I maintain any agent forwarding (such as GitHub) between disconnects.
I use PuTTY as my primary terminal because of many years of ingrained familiarity with the settings and keybinds, the universal portability of it, and having many env tools built around it. Unfortunately, simply "using the built-in terminal in WebStorm" is not a great option.
That's all the info I can think of.

Got it!
The culprit was the Git plugin. Disabled that and my screen session is no longer getting "stolen".
Image of disabled plugin
Tested by running screen -list from a non-screen terminal to confirm there were no Attached sessions, then connected to screen and confirmed that it did not disconnect me again. Turning the plugin back on caused disconnection right away and screen -list reported one Attached session.
My theory is that it runs Git Bash in the background, which is a full terminal and would potentially trigger .bash_profile even if the terminal is hidden from the user.
